# Decomposing an inner product of matrices into outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, outer-product

In a lecture on bayesian reasoning and active learning I came across a slide that seemed to imply that the inner product of a matrix X (of n rows and d columns) with itself could be decomposed into the sum of outer products of row vectors xi (from 1 to n).
My question is two-fold:

1. Is this true?
2. If it is what is the proof?

Comment: What do you mean by the inner product of matrices?

Comment: Meaning the transpose of a matrix multiplied by the matrix (i.e. X_transpose*X)